# Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given

Tags: magento2, controllers

I get the following when using my controller through a front end route.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Namespace\Module\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in
>   /website-magento-2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93 and defined in
>   /Projects/Work/website-magento-2/app/code/Namespace/Module/Controller/Index/index.php:45
>   Stack trace: #0
>   //Projects/Work/website-magento-2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93):
>   Namespace\Module\Controller\Index\Index->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))
>
> #1 /Projects/Work/website-magento-2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Namespace\Module...',
>   Array) #2
>   /Projects/Work/website-magento-2/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.
>   in
>   /Projects/Work/website-magento-2/app/code/Namespace/Module/Controller/Index/index.php
>   on line 45

Controller construct

```
public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        Customer $customer,
        CustomerSession $customerSession,
        Session $catalogSession
    ){
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->customer = $customer;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->catalogSession = $catalogSession;

        parent::__construct($context);

    }
```

I have seen posts about this issue and the resolution is that I delete and regenerate **var/di**, createCharge, **var/cache**.   However this isn't working.

Comment: Try running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` followed by `bin/magento cache:flush`.

Comment: can you clear the cache?

Comment: please provide class definition on your code, may be then i will help u

Comment: could you show your full controller file

Comment: Delete var/generation folder

Comment: for me it was because my controller (extending from frontend action) already has a `$_objectManager` property, so trying to pass that in caused a clash

Answer (score 10):

I have had this type of error as well.
It was a spelling problem, I called to instantiate an object but used a lower case letter in the class name when I should have used an upper case letter.

See also this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164924/24432

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem as well. Similar to the above I was using lowercase in my file names ie "index.php". I changed it to "Index.php" (default controller), recompiled, and it worked.

MacOS, Apache, PHP7

Comment: it is work for me gret