# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to [...] must be an instance of

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, fatal-error, setup-di-compile

I have been having this issue for several weeks now and after looking through similar issues on this site and others, I still can't figure out how to solve this problem.

After successfully executing `setup:di:compile`, the `var/di` folder gets created in my Magento directory. my homepage and CMS pages keep working fine, but after compilation I noticed my category pages (for ex. `domain.com/shop`) give me the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Plazathemes\LayeredNavigation\Controller\Category\View::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in directory/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in directory/www/app/code/Plazathemes/Layerednavigation/Controller/Category/View.php:27 
>   Stack trace: #0 directory/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93): Plazathemes\LayeredNavigation\Controller\Category\View->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager)) #1 directory/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Plazathemes\Lay...', Array) #2 directory/www/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\F in directory/www/app/code/Plazathemes/Layerednavigation/Controller/Category/View.php on line 27

My `code/Plazathemes/LayeredNavigation/Controller/Category/View` file starts with this:

```
class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Category\View
{
    private $layerResolver;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Design $catalogDesign,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Session $catalogSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator $categoryUrlPathGenerator,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        Resolver $layerResolver,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $catalogDesign, $catalogSession, $coreRegistry, $storeManager, $categoryUrlPathGenerator, $resultPageFactory, $resultForwardFactory, $layerResolver, $categoryRepository);
        $this->layerResolver = $layerResolver;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // somthing
    }

}
```

I contacted my theme support but they told me this error is not a result of a bug in their theme.

Anyone who can help me figure this out? I'm fairly new to Magento and quite overwhelmed by all these errors. I've already sorted out most of my problems and errors, but this one keeps coming back.

If you need any additional code, please let me know.

I'm running Magento 2.1.5

EDIT: FYI when I delete my `var/di` folder or just the `global.ser`and `frontend.ser`files in it, the category pages work again but uncompiled, making them extremely slow to load. So I need to sort this out in order to have my compiled files working.

Comment: Which PHP version ur using?

Comment: My PHP version is 7.0.15

Comment: Their theme is working fine on 2.1.3? They have demo for that version?

Comment: Yes they have a working demo which I also tested on my local system with sample data. Their website says the theme is fully compatible with Magento 2.1.x

Comment: Check here `/www/app/code/Plazathemes/Layerednavigation/Controller/Category/View.php on line 27`

Comment: Line 27 is the `public function __construct(...)`

Comment: UPDATE: I am currently upgrading my Magento installation from 2.1.3 to 2.1.5. Will share the results once it's done.

Comment: After upgrading to Magento CE 2.1.5 still the same error.

Comment: In my case it was index.php instead of Index.php in controller :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that in the LN module 2 different namespace declarations was used: `Layerednavigation` and `LayeredNavigation`. When code is compiled all `di` class arguments was stored in the array where the class name with namespace was used as key (string).

[image: log config]

The problem is in the autoloader: it can not find the files because [array keys are case sensitive in the php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19646162/why-are-php-array-keys-case-sensitive) and `Layerednavigation` is different from `LayeredNavigation`.  I don't know why, but Theme developers used 2 different words.  Possibly they just do not test it with compiled version.

I have renamed all namespaces and filenames to the `LayeredNavigation` (camel-case) and all works fine.

**Step-by-step actions:**

1. Change filenames and class names (including namespaces, block names in the layout, etc.) from the `Layerednavigation` to the `LayeredNavigation`
2. Reinstall module
3. Recompile code

**PS:** This question is not off-topic (third party module) because you can change the `Layerednavigation` to another name.

Comment: This is not my error I got but the solution is what I was looking for to find my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The following sequence of actions usually help me to resolve such errors:

- `bin/magento cache:flush`
- remove `var/generation` and `var/di`
- `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Answer (score 1):

Since container-interop/container-interop is deprecated, simply replace it with

`Psr\Container\ContainerInterface` a try. it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As they have extension layout has issue

Go to here -> app/code/Plazathemes/Layerednavigation/view/frontend/layout
in file catalogsearch_result_index.xml

Change this one

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block class="Plazathemes\LayeredNavigation\Block\LayeredNavigation" name="layered.loading.background" as="layered_loading_background" after="-">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="ajaxlayerednavigation/general/enabled">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Plazathemes_Layerednavigation::layerbackground.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

to this one

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block class="Plazathemes\Layerednavigation\Block\Layerednavigation" name="layered.loading.background" as="layered_loading_background" after="-">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="ajaxlayerednavigation/general/enabled">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Plazathemes_Layerednavigation::layerbackground.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

and clear cache your issue solve.