# Error with Dependency Injection in widget

Tags: magento2, error, widget, dependency

I'm a new Magento 2 developer that's trying to create a widget with a picture in it and I've been following some tutorials to get started. 
I'm having some trouble though with dependency injection in the Block-class.

**Here is the error:**

> Error filtering template: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template.php on line 128

The error obviously states that the constructor of the parent if acquiring the wrong information, but as far as I can tell I'm feeding it the correct data.

**Here is my class:**

```
<?php 
namespace X\Y\Block\Widget;

class CustomWidget extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
implements \Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface
{
    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('widget/custom_widget.phtml');
    }
}
```

I've heard across the web though that using the `_toHtml()` function is bad practice and I should use the constructor instead, but that gives me the same effect. So far I've used these constructors:

```
protected function _construct()
{
    parent::_construct();
    $this->setTemplate('widget/custom_widget.phtml');
}

public function _construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::_construct($context, $data);
    $this->setTemplate('widget/custom_widget.phtml');
}
```

I have also tried just setting

> protected $_template = "widget/custom_widget.phtml";

but that generates the same result.

Have anyone seen this before? I have reinstalled Magento several times and my co-workers do not have this problem, so there's definitely something weird going on here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The one underscore in the `public function _construct` method name is typo or you have it in the code?

Comment: Well, right now it is in my code yes, but I've also tried __construct with two underscores and I've seen different sites say different things. Which is correct?

Comment: You should use two underscores in real construct method. The one-underscore construct are called at the end of real construct method in the abstract block & model classes (`\Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel::__construct()` , `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock::__construct()` and maybe somewhere else), but it has no arguments (not compatible with dependency injection).

Comment: Oh wow, I had no idea. Thanks a bunch! I've been working on different things this week but I'll check all the answers here now and see if it solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all of your namespaces, class names, file & folder names. This error can occurs when your namespace is like:

```
Vendor\Module\Block\SomeName\AnotherName
```

and your path to that file is like:

```
Vendor/Module/Block/Somename/Anothername
```

**The second word starts from lowercase**, in this situation, all can work fine before the compilation and doesn't work at all after, because the PHP array-keys is a case-sensitive but namespaces is not case-sensitive.

Here is similar problem with a controller [Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to [...] must be an instance of](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164631/uncaught-typeerror-argument-1-passed-to-must-be-an-instance-of)

Comment: @OscarRomin I was glad to help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, this worked for me on many occasions for creating widgets.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->setTemplate('widget/custom-template.phtml');
    }
```