# Magento2: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to ::__construct() must implement interface

Tags: magento-2.1, module, shipping

I am trying to make a `shipping method` based on `percentage`. Can someone explain to me whats wrong with the following?

***I get this error message:***

```
main.CRITICAL: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to XXX\ShippingPercentage\Model\Carrier\opPercentage::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface, instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given, called in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 93 and defined in /app/code/XXX/ShippingPercentage/Model/Carrier/opPercentage.php on line 25 [] []
```

I think its connected to adding `quoteFactory` as someone mentioned this. However, it's probably in the wrong place. Can someone explain to me how to not get this problem the next time?

```
<?php
namespace XXX\ShippingPercentage\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;
use Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory;

class opPercentage extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $_code = 'oppercentage';

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory
 * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
 * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory
 * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
    $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
    parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any `di.xml` that goes with this module? The error seems to think the 1st parameter in the `__construct` is of the wrong type.

Comment: @DavidManners Nope: /etc/adminhtml/system.xml, /etc/config.xml, /etc/module.xml, /Model/Carrier/opPercentage.php and registration.php

Comment: IT could also be a case sensitive thing. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/164924/158

Comment: clear `var/generated` folder.